# why use PostgreSQL clusterdb instruction

Tags: postgresql

I have come across recommendation for 1C:Enterprise on PostgreSQL. It says that we should periodically use clusterdb command but with no details.

PostgreSQL documentation says: "clusterdb is a utility for reclustering tables in a PostgreSQL database", but what does it mean "reclustering"?
As I come from SQL Server world I might assume that it is the same as rebuilding clustered index, but is that true?

Answer (score 2):

The advice to cluster all tables to gain performance is wrong, ignore it.

What benefits from clustering a table (that is, rewriting the table in the order of one of its indexes) are index scans *on that index* that select many rows. Other than that, clustering is just unnecessary pain.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what are "must have" maintenance tasks for any PostgreSQL database? I am talking about small (<30GB) and large databases.

Comment: Nothing really, except for regular monitored backups.

Comment: What about analyzing, reindexing, vacuuming?

Comment: You don't need to reindex. The rest happens automatically.

Comment: I think reclustering was a recommendation a long time ago, before VACUUM had many improvements, and a VACUUM FULL was so inefficient that it was simpler to reclusters. Definitely outdated advice now though.